# Allow tinytext in db_schema.xml magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, data-migration-tool, database-schema, db-schema

I'm doing a custom migration from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.4 , in one of the custom module on Magento 1.9 it uses tinytext as table column type, therefore I tried to recreate this module using tinytext too in order successfully migrate the data without causing incompatible database table column type.

```
<column name="short" nullable="true" xsi:type="tinytext"/>
```

but I always got an error like this:

> Element 'column', attribute
>   '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}type': The QName value
>   'tinytext' of the xsi:type attribute does not resolve to a type
>   definition.

Answer (score 0):

Tinytext is not there in the allowed types.
You need to change it to text type or check for some other alternative, more suitable type for your case.
Check `vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd` for allowed types.
Read https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html for more details.